# How to create a title page for appendix?

Tags: sectioning, titles, appendix

Currently I use `\usepackage{appendix}`. After command `\appendix`, each `\section{Section Name}` will be shown as "Appendix A. Section Name".

I wish to have a title page for the appendix. Specifically, I want to let the appendix begin with title "Appendix for My Paper XXX" and some description paragraphs, and then start with each section. Is it possible in LaTex?

Comment: You can try to do that with the `titling` package, which yields tools to customise the `\maketitle` command.

Answer (score 2):

As you haven't given an MWE I don't know what you have done but as you mention `\section` I assume you are using the `article` class.

```
% appendixpageprob3.tex  SE 517746 title page and text

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[page]{appendix} % print appendices title
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Appendix for My Paper XXX} % Appendices title
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1]
\clearpage  % move to another page
\begin{appendices}
Some text after the Appendices heading.
\clearpage % move to another page

\section{In appendices}
\lipsum[1]

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Check the documentation (`> texdoc appendix`) for details.